# Jquery reading array in textarea

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, textarea, eval

I need to be able to paste something like this inside a textarea:

```
var cars = new Array(new Array(3), new Array(3));
cars[0][0] = 'FORD';
cars[0][1] = 'Focus';
cars[0][2] = 'Mondeo';
cars[1][0] = 'VOLKSWAGEN';
cars[1][1] = 'Golf';
cars[1][2] = 'Polo';
cars[1][3] = 'Lupo';
```

An afterwards being able to access cars array from my script as a common variable.
Been trying with eval, but after googling I'm really scare of it.
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach arbitrary data to any html element with jquery [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

So given a textarea like this:

```
<textarea id="txa"></textarea>
```

From jquery you could do:

```
var cars = new Array(new Array(3), new Array(3));
cars[0][0] = 'FORD';
...
$('#txa').data('myvar', cars);
```

And then retrieve it later with:

```
var arr = $('#txa').data('myvar');
alert( arr[0][0] ); //alerts FORD
```

**UPDATE:**
Now, based on your last comments, it seems what you just need is the [`eval()`](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/functions/eval-function.php) function to execute the javascript code you have in your textarea, like this:

```
code = $('textarea').val();
eval( code );
alert( arr[0][0] ); //alerts FORD
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/TqMt3/)

Comment: That sounds interesting, I'm going to check it out!

Comment: Hi again, I'm afraid I have explained myself poorly. Unfortunatelly what I currently have is some plain text coming from different external sources with different arrays declarations and I need a way to paste them on a text area and have it available as internal vars.

Comment: Trying to explain it even better, because I'm reading myself and I'm not able to understand me: I need to be able to transform javascript array declarations pasted inside a text area in a form into real arrays ready to be used.

Comment: Ok, based on your last clarification, I've updated my answer with an example to achieve what you want by using `eval()`.

Comment: Remember to accept answer and upvote it if this finally solves your problem, I hope so :-) .

Comment: Consider also upvoting (up arrow) you have enough reputation to do so :-)